# Very simple JavaScript that doesnt work

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

I finally decided to go with a new comment system from [Vicomi](http://www.vicomi.com).
I have entered their website and in 1 minute I had the code to place in my blog.
But, I registered twice and got two tokens.. So, I dont want the service of comment to recognize me, so I removed the token and wrote 123456,
Now, It doesnt work!! 
Do I have to put a token?
This is  the code:

```
<div id="vc-recommend-iframe-wrapper" style="height:300px;"></div><div id="vc-comments- 
iframe-wrapper"></div><script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://api.vicomi.com/embed/widgets.js access_token=123456"></script>
```

Thanks

Victor

Comment: access_token must be valid

Answer (score 2):

The access token is the key used to authenticates you when you are trying to use specific sevice, so it's completely reqired and you cannot use whatever you want.

Read the documentation of service, there you will find all the information you need about the way it works.